# TS utility type info lost with "typeof" operator

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I recently found what looks like a situation where the TS *typeof* operator loses important type information. I suspect it really comes down to a misunderstanding on my part but fortunately it's easy to illustrate:

```
const omit = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(dict: T, key: K) => {
    return dict as Omit<T, K>;
};

// implicit object
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
// full type info available after "omit"
const obj2 = omit(obj, "bar");
// type info is "lossy"
type O2 = typeof obj2;
```

In **vs-code** when I hover over `obj2` it's type is expressed as: `Omit<{foo: number, bar: number}, "bar">`. This is both what I expected and wanted. However, when I hover over the type `O2` I get a type of `{ foo: number }`.

You can see how these two types are similar but the first one contains *more* type information as it has preserved the overall shape of the object along with the omission from that shape.

This is also the case in the slightly more explicit situation where the original object's type is stated:

```
// explicit object
type Start = { foo: number, bar: number};
const obj3: Start = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
// full type info available on obj4
const obj4 = omit(obj3, "bar");
// again "reduced" to just the remaining props
type O4 = typeof obj4;
```

Is there any way in which the *full* type information can be captured by a downstream type definition like `O2` or `O4`? I do understand that in many cases, this *reduced* state is actually preferred as it both simpler and accurate making it easier to grok but in more complex environments this missing information is useful to preserve.

> [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9YVm)

---

I have noticed that if I create an *identity function* and assign another variable through the identity function it preserves type information. This is useful though doesn't entirely address my question.

Example:

```
const omit = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(dict: T, key: K) => {
    return dict as Omit<T, K>;
};

function identity<T>(thing: T):T {
    return thing;
} 

// implicit object
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
// full type info available after "omit"
const obj2 = omit(obj, "bar");
const myObj = identity(obj2);
type O2 = typeof myObj;
```

> typing for both `obj2` and `myObj` are the same and complete; `O2` is still lossy.

Comment: Upvoted because this question is very well asked, although I have a feeling the `typeof` operator deliberately does this, and you may have to store the type based on the return type of your omit function.

Comment: Can you give a use case where preserving the aliasing would be desired? Your second example preserves the alias because of how generics work, but I still fail to see how `Omit<{ foo: number; bar: number; }, "bar">` is more useful than `{ foo: number; }`

Comment: @OlegValter an example would be where you have a Fluent API and you want to "hide" certain keys on the API. The call structure is recursive and each iteration/api-call will want to modify from the existing set of keys. Not sure if that was a good enough explanation.

Comment: @evelynhathaway yes I suspect that typeof is intended to behave this way but my question isn't how to change it's behavior but rather to produce the results I'm intending.

Comment: @ken not sure I understand your explanation... Well, I understand what you are trying to do, but not sure how preserving aliasing helps you here. Too many properties to display when the type is resolved? Don't get me wrong, just asking out of curiosity. As for the task, I am not sure it is possible since to make a type query you'll have to use `typeof`

Comment: @OlegValter it aligns well with the Builder pattern where you expose only those parts of an API surface which are relevant on a per call basis. An interface with `a`, `b` and `c` endpoints may only expose `a` to start, then `b` and `c` and then some other combo. You would typically use a generic to mask the props you don't want and when you recurse on the Fluent API you want to amend this type but to amend it you must make sure it's preserved.